# ROS Answers SE migration: Cmake warning?

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/cmake_modules/cmake/Modules/FindEigen.cmake:62 (message):
The FindEigen.cmake Module in the cmake_modules package is deprecated.

Please use the FindEigen3.cmake Module provided with Eigen.  Change
instances of find_package(Eigen) to find_package(Eigen3).  Check the
FindEigen3.cmake Module for the resulting CMake variable names.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
ROBOTIS/ROBOTIS-THORMANG-MPC-master/ati_ft_sensor/CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)

-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255267/cmake-warning?/) by [GIL](https://answers.ros.org/users/29429/gil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If this is your package you should make the change described in the warning. If this isn't your package, you can probably ignore the warning or file a ticket on the project's bug tracker.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0